# Should it be deliver or delivers?

Tags: grammar

Nano Recommendations delivers editorially relevant videos to your webpages.

Answer (score 2):

I'll cite June Casagrande's *Grammar Snobs Are Great Big Meanies* for this suggestion.  She suggests using the plural form of a verb when the proper noun is plural in nature and the singular form when the proper noun is singular.  Her example is like this one (and might be this one):

> The Rolling Stones are a great band.
>
> The Who is also a great band.

Since the proper noun in your sentence is plural, the verb can be too.

Comment: But Manchester United are an underperforming football team!

Comment: I should have included that June Casagrande is writing for an American audience even though I used British bands.  I should have used The Ramones and Lynyrd Skynyrd.